# What is meant by the phase "roving inquiry"?

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

HC remarks on Jayalalithaa death probe panel are a needed caution against a roving inquiry.

"Roving" means "not restricted to one place". But that doesn't seem to fit here. So, what could it possibly mean?

Comment: Googling **a roving inquiry** provides the answer: https://www.casemine.com/search/in?q=roving+inquiry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roving enquiry means

> roving inquiry refers to asking questions which are not at all connected with the subject matter.

Comment: Such questions, which are not pertinent to an inquiry, are more commonly referred to as **fishing**.

Answer (score 0):

Roving enquiry as referred to in judgements perhaps means that Judges are not to sift through the whole matter while deciding at the time of Argument on charge